# Where are the Openstack images stored?

Tags: openstack

I have a **openstack private cloud** deployed at my organization. I have some **virtual images** like ubuntu image, windows image which are uploaded through the openstack dashboard. But i would like to know **where the images are stored** in the openstack controller node.

I tried to go through path : **/etc/glance** and **/var/lib/glance** . But its **not listing any** of the images which are uploaded.

It would be great if i could get an insight about the same.

Answer (score 5):

Glance is the image manager for OpenStack.  So we're going to need to hop onto one of your glance API nodes.

Depending on how glance is configured, your glance may be storing images in a myriad of potential backends.  Ranging from files in a directory to on a swift object store.

Check out /etc/glance/glance.conf to see what format your images are being stored in.

```
default_store=STORE
```

STORE would be the format the images are stored in.  The default format is file.

If it's file's as I assume it is.

Check /etc/glance/glance.conf for this attribute:

```
filesystem_store_datadir=PATH
```

PATH would be where the images are.  If this isn't set, it will default to:

```
Default: /var/lib/glance/images/
```

ref:  http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/configuring.html

Answer (score 3):

`Default: /var/lib/glance/images/`

Answer (score 1):

All the images will be listed by their image id's, so you'll need to check the image id either from command line using `nova image-list` or `glance image-list`.

From the web UI, click on project then under compute select images and click on the image name, look for the id and using the id check for the image under /var/lib/glance/images.

Answer (score 1):

From the following command you can find the list of images uploaded in the environment.

```
$ glance image-list
```

Check the images list and if you want to download the image from the image list user the following command:

```
$ glance image-download <imagename> > <imagename.qcow2>
```

it will download the image into the location where you execute the command.